# How can i get center x,y of my view in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am attaching an imageview up on my frame layout. Here i want to get my imageview center co-ordinates. i will use that same co-ordinates to set my imageview in next layout. Please suggest me how to get the center co-ordinates of my imageview.

Thanks in advance

Comment: After the view has been created? What have you tried?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

centre of the imageView will be

```
 centreX=imageView.getX() + imageView.getWidth()  / 2;
 centreY=imageView.getY() + imageView.getHeight() / 2;
```

but make sure you call it after the imageView created

Comment: Seems getX() and getY() can not be used when api level below 11

Comment: What if the imageView is scaled ?

Comment: this solution is only relative to parent view. If you want it to be global you should use the getLocationOnScreen or getLocationInWindow methods

Comment: centreX and centreY will be float

Answer (score 9):

You can use `getPivotX()` and `getPivotY()`, it always keep in center of view even rotate view.

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: @aiueoH : is it possible to get the center?

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
ImageView my_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageView);  

Rect rectf = new Rect();
my_image.getLocalVisibleRect(rectf);

Log.d("WIDTH        :",String.valueOf(rectf.width()));
Log.d("HEIGHT       :",String.valueOf(rectf.height()));
Log.d("left         :",String.valueOf(rectf.left));
Log.d("right        :",String.valueOf(rectf.right));
Log.d("top          :",String.valueOf(rectf.top));
Log.d("bottom       :",String.valueOf(rectf.bottom));
```

Hope this helps you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As @aiueoH mentioned, you can use `getPivotX() and getPivotY()`.

Try using this for finding coordinates of centre:

```
int centreX = view.getPivotX()/2;
int centreY = view.getPivotY()/2;
```

Comment: Perhaps divide by 2 is unneeded?  The [documentation states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isPivotSet()) "If no pivot has been set then the pivot will be the center of the view."

Answer (score 2):

if you wish to align a view at the center of other view then you can use this -

```
float center_x = parent_view.getX() + parent_view.getWidth()/2 - child_view.getWidth()/2;
```

and then obviously using -

```
child_view.setX(center_x);
```

Comment: This is perfect answer. when you want to set textview center in view than this solution works. above solutions not gives perfect center x.

Comment: Working, thanks