# Center of the view after rotation or scale

Tags: android, image-rotation

I am trying to find the center of a view. For non-rotated view the value is correct, but for rotated view it's not correct as the centre(0,0) is rotating. In the case of scaling the width and height is keep constant even after zooming

I am using the following formula to calculate the center.

```
 int[] location = new int[2];
 childView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
 int xLocation = location[0] + childView.getWidth() / 2;
 int yLocation = location[1] + childView.getHeight() / 2
```

from `getGlobalVisibleRect` i get the rect of visible part only

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve? what zooming do you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get center x,y of my view in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758654/how-can-i-get-center-x-y-of-my-view-in-android)

Comment: With out scaling or rotation the above is correct

Comment: so call `View#getMatrix()`  and use that `Matrix` for mapping any points you want (not only center point)

Comment: How to get center from matrix

Comment: `Matrix` has many "mapping" methods, read the documentation

Comment: @pskink :  i checked the mapping method , but none of them gave me the  correct value. getGlobalVisibleRect gaves the coorect value but when some part of the view  is not visibile  is  the value get changing

Comment: so what is your code?

Comment: @pskink i just need the center of a scaled rotated view. i tried so may ways

Comment: so what is your code? how did you use a `Matrix`?

Comment: @pskink : there is no way in Rect from Matrix. only to apply Rect using matrix

Comment: what have you tried with a `Matrix`? did you call `View#getMatrix()`? what have you done with that `Matrix` then?

Comment: @pskink : i didn't find anything after that just angle and scale factor. Translation based on orgin

Comment: so what `Matrix` "mapping" methods did you try? (`i checked the mapping method , but none of them gave me the correct value`)

Comment: mapRect(RectF dst, RectF src) , mapRadius(float radius), mapPoints(float[] dst, float[] src)

Comment: ok and `mapPoints` does not work? what was your code? what float array did you pass to that method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132105/discussion-between-v-v-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getHitRect(android.graphics.Rect)

This method will return you Rect(considering rotation and scale) within its parent view